# Can't output simple array?

Tags: coldfusion

I've been trying to figure out why my array won't output.

I did a var dump on the array and it dumps it just fine but when I try to output it, it returns fatal error. In addition, I figured that maybe I had to probably loop over the array in order to access it, so I tried that too and managed to loop over the array by doing a var dump but when I output it, it breaks the page.

Here is my code that I attempted i've been trying for almost 3 hours now trying various things.

ColdFusion:

```
<cfset defaultDirectory = "C:\uploads\" />

<cfdirectory
   directory="#defaultDirectory#"
   action="list"
   name="myList"
>

<!---Get Array of Directory Names --->
<cfquery dbtype="query" name="fileNames">
    SELECT NAME
    FROM myList
</cfquery>

<!---Create array --->
<cfset myArray=arraynew(1)>

<!---Populate array with directory query data "name" --->
<cfloop query="fileNames">
    <cfset myArray[CurrentRow][1]=#defaultDirectory# & NAME & "\">
</cfloop
```

Up to this point, everything seemed to be going good. I dumped out the array variable and it outputted what I wanted. So I tried this and it returned a fatal error.

```
<cfoutput>

<cfif directoryExists("#myArray[1]#")>
   it exists.
   <cfelse>
   Doesn't exists.
</cfif>

<cfoutput>
```

Here is the screenshot of the variable being dumped.
 [image]

What I then figured was maybe I have to loop over the array in order to access it?

so I tried this.

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(myArray)#">
   <cfdump var="#myArray[i]#"
</cfloop>
```

this managed to dump out all things from the array but when i try to output it, it returns a fatal error I'm not sure why. I looked up tutorials on how to dump the array and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is a screenshot of the structure of myArray that was requested:

I did

```
<cfvar dump="#myArray#">
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the dumped out array so we can examine the structure.

Comment: Is that what you wanted? that is the structure of the myArray variable being dumped.

Comment: Yes. So you have an array of structures. I will post an answer as it will give me more space to describe this.

Comment: Not sure what the overall objective is, but you might be doing too much work.  `<cfdirectory>` returns a query upon which you can perform array functions.  At the very least, the filenames q of q looks redundant.

Comment: My objective is this. I need to grab folder locations of everything in Local C:\, once I do that, push it into an array. Then, loop over array and check to see if a certain value is equal to any of these folder directories that I stored in the array. If it is, upload it to that specific folder directory. If it isn't create a new directory from the array variable.

Comment: We think differently.  It sounds like your objective, as I define objective, is to create directories in location B that exist in location A, but not B.  In my mind, what you call an objective, I call a way to achieving that objective.  The reason I mention it is that there is usually more than one way to achieve an objective and someone on this forum might suggest a better one.

Comment: You're right. Matter of fact I just figured out a different way to achieve what I was looking for rather than storing these directories in a array. I instead, wrote a SQL query that grabbed a location from a table, checked to see if that location was in the page session, if it was, upload it, if it wasn't create new directory with location from SQL query. So basically I managed to figure out how to do it differently with SQL and ColdFusion together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array of structures. So you cannot simply output the array value as a string; that is why you are getting an error.

You need to reference the array index as well as the structure's key to extract the value. Something like this pseudo-code: `arrayName[arrayIndex][structureKey]`. It looks like you have it working in the initial code example. Here:

```
<cfset myArray[CurrentRow][1]=#defaultDirectory# & NAME & "\">
```

It was confusing to me because your structure key happens to be the number `1`. So it looked like an index or something.

I created a gist to show you a working example - [TryCF Gist](https://trycf.com/gist/bcd142aa90d40fa10c6e702e6f665c24/acf2016?theme=monokai).
Here is the code I wrote:

```
<cfscript>
structA = {1="C:\uploads\101 San Fernando"};
structB = {1="C:\uploads\121 Tasman"};
structC = {1="C:\uploads\360 Residences"};
structD = {1="C:\uploads\481 On Mathilda"};

myArray = [];
ArrayAppend(myArray,structA);
ArrayAppend(myArray,structB);
ArrayAppend(myArray,structC);
ArrayAppend(myArray,structD);

writeDump(myArray);

//writeOutput(myArray[1][1]);

for (i=1;i LTE ArrayLen(myArray);i=i+1) {
  writeOutput('<p>' & myArray[i][1] & '</p>');
}
</cfscript>
```

The output for that code is:

[image]

So your code should look like this:

```
<cfif directoryExists("#myArray[1][1]#")>
   it exists.
<cfelse>
   Doesn't exists.
</cfif>
```

Or if you wrap that in a loop like this:

```
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#arrayLen(myArray)#">
    <cfif directoryExists("#myArray[i][1]#")>
       it exists.
    <cfelse>
       Doesn't exists.
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Very helpful