# Access elements Coldfusion Array

Tags: coldfusion

This must a very simple one. But I am having hard time getting it right. I have a object as below which I am trying to access using coldfusion. [image]. My object like shown below is more complex than the suggested post. It has array in a struct inside an array.

I want to access the Second Arrays struct Value that is '123'. I am able to access the first array value which is '456' using below.

```
      <cfset arr_test = the_dump[y].CustomFields[1].values/>
        <cfif ArrayIsDefined(arr_test , 1)>
            <cfset args.type = arr_test [1]/>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset args.type = ''/>
        </cfif>
```

But if I do something like this to access the second value I get undefined.

```
      <cfset arr_test_next = the_dump[y].CustomFields[2].values/>
        <cfif ArrayIsDefined(arr_test_next , 2)>
            <cfset args.type_next = arr_test_next [2]/>
        <cfelse>
            <cfset args.type_next = ''/>
        </cfif>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't output simple array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46432318/cant-output-simple-array)

Comment: The object I have is more complex than the example you have referred to. Any ideas on how to access the array inside of struct inside of an array.

Comment: Try using hash table / query object to store such results. It is easy to hande and visualize. You can also try the CFlib UDF [QueryToArrayOfStructures](http://www.cflib.org/udf/QueryToArrayOfStructures)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can help better with actual data, so I've tried to reconstruct your structure...

```
the_dump = [{
    'CustomFields': [{
        'FieldName': 'fn1',
        'Fieldtype': 'ft1',
        'Values': ['a','b','c']
    },{
        'FieldName': 'fn2',
        'Fieldtype': 'ft2',
        'Values': ['d','e','f']   
    }]
}];
```

With that, a...

```
writeDump(the_dump);
```

Gives me this...

[image]

And I can access the second array like this no problem...

```
arr_test = the_dump[1].CustomFields[2].values;
writeDump(arr_test);
```

[image]

This is essentially what you have, with the possible exception of the `y` variable. So my guess is that's where the problem is.

Similarly, passing an index of 1 or 2 to `ArrayIsDefined` both return 'YES' as well...

```
arr = the_dump[1].CustomFields;
isarr = ArrayIsDefined(arr, 2);
writeDump(isarr); // YES
```

For reference, here's copy/pasteable code I used at https://trycf.com

```
<cfscript>
the_dump = [{
    'CustomFields': [{
        'FieldName': 'fn1',
        'Fieldtype': 'ft1',
        'Values': ['a','b','c']
    },{
        'FieldName': 'fn2',
        'Fieldtype': 'ft2',
        'Values': ['d','e','f']   
    }]
}];

writeDump(the_dump);

arr_test = the_dump[1].CustomFields[2].values;
writeDump(arr_test);

arr = the_dump[1].CustomFields;
isarr = ArrayIsDefined(arr, 2);
writeDump(isarr);

</cfscript>
```

Comment: Nicely explained. There is more than one way to manipulate such structures though.